# So, rewrote my camera code (sort of) and I'm back at square one

Tags: c++

I'm back!

So, I rewrote my camera code. Here's the new code:

```
OldMouseX = MouseX;
OldMouseY = MouseY;

GetCursorPos(&p);

MouseX = p.x - CenterX;
MouseY = p.y - CenterY;


//Camera moving left/right

heading += MouseX - OldMouseX;
yrot = heading;

heading += MouseX - OldMouseX;
yrot = heading;

//Camera moving up/down

VertLook += MouseY - OldMouseY;

VertLook += MouseY - OldMouseY;

SetCursorPos(CenterX, CenterY);
```

However, with the call of `SetCursorPos(CenterX, CenterY);` my camera goes back to only jerking slightly thus putting me back at square one. With `SetCursorPos(CenterX, CenterY);` commented, it works fine. Any solutions to get it working properly with `SetCursorPos(CenterX, CenterY);`?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why do you write those lines twice?

Comment: @Blindy OMG I didn't even realize it was like that! My bad!

Comment: Please use a descriptive question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rotation deltas aren't relative to whatever `OldMouseX` and `OldMouseY` are, they're relative to the center of your screen (presumably `CenterX` and `CenterY`). That's the whole point of wrapping the cursor back to the center.

Comment: Alright, so with that, my camera goes berserk. Has a mind of its own. Rotates in all directions nonstop.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. If you snapshot the delta from the center, use it to rotate then move the cursor back to the center, you have to actively move the cursor for anything to happen. If you're seeing non-stop motion then I suggest whatever is in `CenterX` and `CenterY` is wrong information. Hence the **presumably** above.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I just realized that I was subtracting CenterX and CenterY twice.